# Printing Vertical Histogram to console

Tags: java, console, histogram

I am required to write a void method() "printHistogram(int bin)" that prints a histogram of owners with respect to the dog they own. The argument is "int bin" that is used to divide the histogram into intervals. At most a user can have 10 dogs. Thus, consider bin = 5, the interval in this case would be 2 since 10/5 = 2. Hence, intervals of (0-5, 5-10) would be made.

```
_
_
_
_     _
0-5  5-10
```

Something like that, which means 4 users have dogs between 0 to 5 and so forth. No need to know the methods of getting dog count etc. I just need the logic and algorithm. I really need help. Thanks. The output of this method is to print "_" underscores and construct a vertical histogram.

This is my code:-

```
public void drawHistogram(int bin) {

      int highestDogs = owners.get(0).countDogs(); //method for getting number of dogs of a user
      int intervals = 10/bin;
      int temp = 0;
      int tempBin = bin;

      for (int i =0; i < owners.size(); i++) 
      {
         tempBin = bin;
         temp = 0;
         do{
            System.out.println(i + "iteration" + " " + owners.get(i).countDogs() );
            if(owners.get(i).countDogs() >= temp && owners.get(i).countDogs() < tempBin)
            {

               if( tempBin > bin)
               {

                  System.out.print("    ");  
               }


               System.out.print("_  ");
               temp = tempBin;
               tempBin = bin + bin;
               System.out.println(tempBin);

            }
            else { 
               temp = tempBin;
               tempBin = bin + bin;

               System.out.println(tempBin);
            }

         }while(tempBin < 11);
         System.out.println();
      }

   }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a challenging task. Do you have any pseudo-code or first attempts yet ?

Comment: And what conclusions did you come to after trying for days?

Comment: I edited my question. I edited my code several times, Right now, I dont even know if I am in the right direction.

Comment: I have no clue what it suppose to do, what is the input and what is expected outcome ;(

Comment: edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that draws an histogram. Note the comments :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    static List<Integer> owners;  //represents number of dogs per owner
    static final int MAX_DOGS_NUM = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //test data
        owners = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6});
        drawHistogram(2);
    }

    static void drawHistogram(int bin) {

        //todo add check to make sure bin < MAX_DOGS_NUM
        List<Column> columns = makeColumns(bin);
        calcColumnsData(columns);
        System.out.println(new Histogram(columns));
    }

    //construct all columns, set interval ends 
    private static List<Column> makeColumns(int bin) {

        List<Column> columns = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0 ; i <= MAX_DOGS_NUM ; i += bin ) {
            int intervalEnd = (i+ bin) > MAX_DOGS_NUM ? MAX_DOGS_NUM : (i+ bin);
            columns.add(new Column(i, intervalEnd));
            i++;
        }
        return columns;
    }

    //calculate quantity of each column 
    private static void calcColumnsData(List<Column> columns) {

        for(Column col : columns) {
            //count the number of owners who has dogs within interval 
            int ownersCounter = 0;   
            for(int numberOfDogs : owners) {
                if((numberOfDogs >= col.getInteravalStart())
                        && (numberOfDogs <= col.getIntervalEnd())) { ownersCounter++ ;}
            }
            col.setQty(ownersCounter); //update column quantity 
        }
    }
}

//represents a single histogram column
class Column {
    //interval ends, quantity of owners 
    int interavalStart, intervalEnd, qty =0;

    Column(int interavalStart, int intervalEnd) {
        this.interavalStart = interavalStart;
        this.intervalEnd = intervalEnd;
    }

    int getQty() {  return qty; }

    void setQty(int qty) {  this.qty = qty; }

    int getInteravalStart() {return interavalStart; }

    int getIntervalEnd() {return intervalEnd; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return interavalStart +"-" +intervalEnd+": "+ qty;
    }
}

//represents histogram graph
class Histogram{

    private List<Column> columns; //histogram columns 
    //representation of graph mark and space 
    private static final String MARK = "-", SPACE =" ";
    private static final int COLUMN_WIDTH = 8; 
    private int maxHeight =0; //size of highest histogram 
    //histogram data. each row contains makrs or space. last 
    //row contains footer 
    private String graphRepresentation[][]; 

    Histogram(List<Column> columns) {
        this.columns = columns;
        calculateMaxHeight();
        prepareGraphRepresentation();
    }

    //find tallest column 
    private void calculateMaxHeight() {
        for(Column col : columns) {
            if(col.getQty() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = col.getQty();}
        }
        maxHeight +=1; //add 1 for column footer
    }

    //fill graphRepresentation with spaces, marks or footer 
    private void prepareGraphRepresentation() {

        graphRepresentation = new String[maxHeight][columns.size()];

        for(int colIndex = 0 ; colIndex < columns.size() ; colIndex ++ ) {

            Column col = columns.get(colIndex);
            int rowCounter = 0;

            for(int rowIndex = maxHeight -1 ; rowIndex >=0; rowIndex -- ) {

                String s = SPACE;
                if (rowCounter == 0 ) { //histogram footer
                     s = col.getInteravalStart()+"-"+col.getIntervalEnd();
                }else if(rowCounter <= col.getQty()) {
                    s = MARK;
                }
                graphRepresentation[rowIndex][colIndex] = format(s);
                rowCounter++;
            }
        }
    }

    //add spaces to s to make it as wide as column width
    private String format(String s) {

        int leftSpaces = (COLUMN_WIDTH - s.length())/2;
        int rightSpaces = COLUMN_WIDTH - s.length() - leftSpaces;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        //add left spaces
        for(int spaces =0 ; spaces <leftSpaces; spaces++) {
            sb.append(SPACE);
        }
        sb.append(s);
        for(int spaces =0 ; spaces <rightSpaces; spaces++) {
            sb.append(SPACE);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(String[] row : graphRepresentation ) {
            for(String s : row ) {
                sb.append(s);
            }
            sb.append("\n");
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]